# I can't change the button image in tkinter Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am new to Python and for sure this has a simple answer. I would appreciate your help and here is my code :)

```
    def Button1B():
        if button1['image'] == play:
            button1['image'] = loop
    play=PhotoImage(file="play.png")
    loop=PhotoImage(file="loop.png")
    button1=Button(frame, image=play, bg="#292929", bd=0, activebackground="#292929", cursor="hand2", command=Button1B)
    button1.place(x=15, y=450)
```

Comment: If you execute `print(play)` after creating `play`, you will get something like `pyimage`.  So the if statement is always evaluated as False.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code and change it to your style:

```
def button_change():
    button1.configure(image=loop_image)


frame = Tk()
frame.title('image')

play_image = PhotoImage(file="start.png")
loop_image = PhotoImage(file="stop.png")

button1 = Button(frame, image=play_image, command=button_change)
button1.place(x=15, y=450)

frame.mainloop()
```

This is output:
[image]

[image]